# Automatically break long function signatures, calls, etc

Tags: package, functions, formatting, programming

```
void parse(std::vector<float>& io_vertices, std::vector<unsigned>& io_indices) {}
```

Oftentimes when we code we need to break lines repeatedly as new expressions and statements enter the picture and our rows veer ever-closer to the column limit. We break function signatures, calls, etc., and line up arguments nicely:

```
void parse(std::vector<float>& io_vertices,
           std::vector<unsigned>& io_indices) {}
```

When it comes to plain text or comments, `fill-paragraph` is a lifesaver. Auto-formatting code, on the other hand, is notoriously difficult [but not impossible](http://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2015/09/08/the-hardest-program-ive-ever-written/).
Surely someone must've made the effort in Emacs!

I've been (fruitlessly) trying to find a set of commands or a package that can do this for me, in particular for C and C++ like languages. Either attempts are rare or options so obvious that they elude me. This is the simplest solution to doing what I want:

```
(defun lazy-break-args ()
  (interactive)
  (let ((tokens (split-string (thing-at-point 'line t) ", ")))
    (unless (= (length tokens) 1)
      (let* ((breaks (mapcar (lambda (p) (format "%s,\n" p)) (butlast tokens)))
             (lines (append breaks (last tokens))))
        (move-beginning-of-line nil)
        (kill-line 1)
        (mapc (lambda (l) (insert l) (indent-according-to-mode)) lines)))))
```

Clearly this task depends on whatever language it is you're using, but my question is purposefully open to both language-specific packages (up to full-fledged formatters) and home-brew hacks like mine (*"break and indent at commas, what the heck!"*).

Are there any functions in Emacs already, or any packages, that can do this? *I don't expect perfection.*

Comment: Please *specify* just what you mean by such a break-up. Presumably it's about breaking lines (or perhaps escaping newline chars), but what kind of breaking -- **where**? Otherwise, although you might get some helpful replies, the question is a bit too broad. Please say what you mean, to help others help you better.

Comment: Hey, @Drew, I added some more detail to make my question less vague, but really it's meant to be somewhat open-ended. I hope it's clear why!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had good luck with [multi-line](https://github.com/IvanMalison/multi-line)

which, without configuration, allows you to cycle through different white space policies with a single repeated key press.

```
(use-package "multi-line" :bind ("C-;"))
```

Comment: There's a [related question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/20714/how-to-break-long-lines-automatically) specifically for Python that's left unanswered. This package should help; I think you should drop an answer there too!

Answer (score 1):

CC mode provides for automatically filling text in comments and strings out-of-the-box. See the description in the manual: [Filling and Breaking](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Filling-and-Breaking.html)

By default, filling in CC mode ignores code. If you want, you can enable it by editing the value of `c-ignore-auto-fill`, as explained in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/ccmode/Custom-Filling-and-Breaking.html#Custom-Filling-and-Breaking).